# I have a custom google map. How can I create a link that sends users to the custom map,and then to specific location?

Tags: google-maps, url, location, maps

I have a google map with alot of custom locations.

How do I send users to not only THAT custom map, but a specific  location on the the map as well?

So when a person clicks on a url,the custom map is loaded,and the user is sent to a specific  location.

Answer (score 0):

I know here you can find a way you can send new markers to the users [HERE](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/storing-google-maps-android-api-v2-marker-locations-in-mysql/)